# Tomcat clustering - configuring 2 tomcats on different machines

Tags: session, tomcat, session-replication

I'm trying to create a tomcat cluster in order to replicate sessions.

my 2 tomcats are existing on two different machines,

All examples available showed clustering of 2 tomcats on same machine.

Where do i configure the ips of the tomcats in the configuration files?

(currently when i use the default configurations i get the error:"

```
Oct 30, 2013 10:21:03 AM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager getAllClusterSessions
INFO: Manager [localhost#/HATest]: skipping state transfer. No members active in cluster group."
```

Thanks!

EDIT: my (default and not so interesting) server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
     -->
   <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
   define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
   Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
    -->
  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
   -->
```

```
<!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
<!--
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->


<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
-->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
 <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Comment: Provide your server.xml file. Also explain how you tried to cluster?

Comment: I just tried to quick clustering with understanding that i wont work for 2 tomcats that are not on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

For the default cluster configuration to work between multipl machines, multicast needs to be working. If the nodes can't see each then then the chances are that multicast is not enabled in one or more of the machnes / blocked at the network level / machines are on a different subnet.

In this case, you can use static membership to explicitly define the other machines in the cluster. See the [Tomcat clustering docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/cluster-interceptor.html#Static_Membership) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<Host></Host>`, you need to do clustering.

Make use of the following example to modify your `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="site1.mydomain.net" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" directory="logs" prefix="virtual_log1." suffix=".log" timestamp="true"/>
<Context path="" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapp" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>

<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="10.99.60.170"
                  port="8082"
                  selectorTimeout="100"
                  maxThreads="6"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>

            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
                <Member className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
                      port="8083"
                      securePort="-1"
                      host="10.99.60.172"
                      domain="staging-cluster"
                      uniqueId="{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}"/>

            </Interceptor>
        </Channel>

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

<ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
<ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>

  <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
            tempDir="/usr/share/tomcat/temp/"
            deployDir="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/"
            watchDir="/usr/share/tomcat/watch/"
            watchEnabled="true"/>

</Cluster>
</Host>
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats the different ips im seeing in your xml? whaths the difference between the reciever address and member's host?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use configuration as per below server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8011" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
        <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
        <Manager         className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                                expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                                notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                                        address="228.0.0.4"
                                        port="45566"
                                        frequency="500"
                                        dropTime="3000"/>

                <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                        <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                </Sender>

                <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                                        address="172.16.17.244"
                                        port="4002"
                                        autoBind="100"
                                        selectorTimeout="5000"
                                        maxThreads="6"/>

                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>

                <!--  <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>  
                -->

                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
                    <Member className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
                          port="4001"
                          securePort="-1"
                          host="192.168.80.128"
                          domain="staging-cluster"
                          uniqueId="{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}"/>
                </Interceptor>

        </Channel>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>


        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>

        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>


        </Cluster>

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

In this xml please refer bellow tag...

```
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
            <Member className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
                  **port="4001"**
                  securePort="-1"
                  **host="192.168.80.128"**
                  domain="staging-cluster"
                  uniqueId="{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}"/>
        </Interceptor>
```

In this 
host = system ip of the tomcat running on another machine and 
port = receiver port of the tomcat running on another machine

In below receiver tag  ...

```
<Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                                    address="172.16.17.244"
                                    port="4002"
                                    autoBind="100"
                                    selectorTimeout="5000"
                                    maxThreads="6"/>
```

address = is current machines ip address

Make these above changes in server.xml of tomcat running on current machine.

Similar changes need to be done in server.xml of tomcat running on other machine; only system ips and port will change.

Hope this will help you..