# Tomcat clustering with Apache2.4 and mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, apache2.4, mod-jk

I have a task of clustering web-service in order not to stop processing requests while deploing updates.

I developed ***test model*** including Apache2.4 server, mod_jk and two Tocat6 workers. Test model with all it's components are on single machine. Configuration I used is the most simple.

***Test model*** works fine. And I can see that both workers are aware of each other states, and there no problem to users while I'm deploying updates.

The model we prepare for production includes two machines:

1. Apache2.4, mod_jk, Tomcat(Worker1)
2. Tomcat (Worker2)

I have changed configuration a little and ***production model*** stated work like test model except one detail.

It seems to me that in ***production model*** both workers (on different machines) are not aware of each other's existence. And no session replications ocures. My workers logs contains records like this

**No members active in cluster group**
**SEVERE: FarmWarDeployer can only work as host cluster subelement!**

while I know for sure that both Tomcats running.

**server.xml(worker1)** includes Cluster section like this

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker1">

   <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
            <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" 
                     expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" 
                     notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

            <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" 
                            address="228.0.0.4" 
                            port="45564" 
                            frequency="500" 
                            dropTime="3000"/>
                <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 
                          address="auto" 
                          port="4000" 
                          tcpListenPort="4007"
                          selectorTimeout="100" 
                          maxThreads="6"/>
                <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                    <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                </Sender>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
           </Channel>

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" 
                   filter=""/>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
            <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer" 
                      tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/" 
                      deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/" 
                      watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/" 
                      watchEnabled="false"/>

            <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
            <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>    
        </Cluster>      

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        </Host>
    </Engine>
```

**server.xml(worker2)** have difference only in port numbers

```
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker2">
       <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
            <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" 
                     expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" 
                     notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

            <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" 
                                address="228.0.0.4" 
                                port="45564" 
                                frequency="500" 
                                dropTime="3000"/>
                <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 
                              address="auto" 
                              port="4000" 
                              tcpListenPort="4006"
                              selectorTimeout="100" 
                              maxThreads="6"/>
                <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                    <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                </Sender>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>

            </Channel>

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" 
                   filter=""/>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
            <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer" 
                      tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/" 
                      deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/" 
                      watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/" 
                      watchEnabled="false"/>

            <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
            <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>    
        </Cluster>

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

My question is: how to configure my **production model** properly? All the samples I have find used the model equal to my ***test model***.

Comment: Here I found solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677600/tomcat-clustering-configuring-2-tomcats-on-different-machines

Comment: Now I'm facing very strange problem.